# Create new variable based on position and value of other variables

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create new variables based on the position of `Var_1` through `Var_8` and the value of `Value_1` through `Value_4`. The data is in panel form with `ID` repeating every **5** rows. For example, for the 5 `IDs` and first Var_# that is populated with 1's, the corresponding `NVar_#`, should take the five values in `Value_1`. For the same **5** `IDs` and second `Var_#` that is populated with 1's, the corresponding `NVar_#`, should take the five values in `Value_2`. And so on.

In the picture below, `Var_1` is populated with 1s in the first ID block. Therefore, `NVar_1` should have the first block of values from `Value_1`. `Var_3` is also populated with 1s in the first `ID` block. Therefore, NVar_3 should have the first block of values from `Value_2`. And so on.

The pattern of 1s every **5** `IDs` in `Var_1-8` is variable, but only 4 columns in each `ID` block will be populated with 1s. The values in `Value_1-4` repeat every **5** `IDs`.

Any direction on VBA syntax or excel formulas is appreciated.

Here is what the output should look like. 
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to format your text, it is so painful to read... use ` to format inline code, `**` for bold and `*` for italic. And all of this is just above the text editor!

Comment: It looks as if you could use an INDEX formula to get the answers that you want but won't have time to do it and test it right now.

Comment: Thanks @TomSharpe! I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Var_1 entries start in B2, I came up with this under NVar_1 copied down and across:-

```
=IF(B2,INDEX($J$2:$M$4,ROWS($N$1:$N1),COUNTIF($B2:B2,1)),0)
```

So you get the value from the same row, but with a column that is determined by the COUNTIF - this counts the number of ones in Var_1, Var_2 etc. up to the matching column (or you could just use SUM to count the number of ones).

Actually you can simplify it just to work in the current row like this:-

```
=IF(B2,INDEX($J2:$M2,1,COUNTIF($B2:B2,1)),0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @TomSharp. I get `#Ref` in the locations where there should be data when the formulas get the the second block of **IDs**. Any ideas as to what is going wrong? I don't really understand how the rows part is working.

Comment: OK, if I restart ROWS($N$1:$N1) each block, then it works. Only missing piece is to figure out how to restart it or get the rows part to cycle values 1-5 each block